# Android databinding variable list with Any type

Tags: android, android-databinding

maybe someone knows how to add `List<Any>` or `List<*>` variable in databinding with any type?

When type is known it is done like this:

```
<data>

    <import type="java.util.List" />

    <variable
        name="list"
        type="List&lt;String>" />
</data>
```

Answer (score 4):

answering my own question:

```
 <data>

        <import type="java.util.List" />

        <variable
            name="list"
            type="List&lt;Object>" />
    </data>
```

Key is using `Object`